# python3 TemporaryDirectory() invalid file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

iam trying to create a TemporaryFile in a TemporaryDirectory in python 3 but when i run the program in windows i get a [WinError267] the directory name is invalid
i think it is due to the windows ""  in file naming but i use the join fucntion to make the name

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tdp:
    path = os.path.join(tdp, "tempfile.txt")
    tfp = open(path, "w+t")
    tfp.write("This is a temp file in temp dir")
    tfp.seek(0)
    print(tfp.read())
```

Comment: change "tempfile.txt" to "/tempfile.txt"

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος That shouldn't be necessary with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: Try: `os.path.join(tdp.name, "tempfile.txt")`. Or just use [`tempfile.TemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp there is no such attribute

Comment: You are right. I was thinking of something else. I tried your code and - after fixing indentation - got it to work by using: `with open(path, "w+t") as tfp:`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your code only works (after fixing indentation) on Windows by using `with` in the file open (which you should use anyway).

```
import tempfile
import os

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tdp:
    path = os.path.join(tdp, "tempfile.txt")
    with open(path, "w+t") as tfp:
        tfp.write("This is a temp file in temp dir")
        tfp.seek(0)
        print(tfp.read())
```

If the filename is not important, just use `tempfile.TemporaryFile`:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="w+t") as tfp:
    tfp.write("This is a temp file in temp dir")
    tfp.seek(0)
    print(tfp.read())
```

Comment: thank you it did work with the context manager . but i still don't know why it worked on mac without it ,